# how to fix vulnerabilitie segment in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, security, code-injection

i am not the strongest js user, but i need it and i wrote some code for my webpage which works on apache and php. in my ajax requests i have that code in

```
if (dataX['var1'] == '1.1' || dataX['var1'] == '2.1')
{
    window.location.href = '<domain>'
}
```

if i use XSStrike to check potential VULNERABILITIES on my system i get the message that maybe that part could be injected.

can someone help me to fix that if it is needed? do i need something like freeze or other stuff to fix that? Sry but i dont see how attackers could use that. thx for any usefull help. br

what i try? i try to ask on that channel?!

Comment: try strict checking. `===` instead of `==`, what does `<domain>` contain? how is it populated?

Answer (score 0):

If `<domain>` can contain arbitrary unchecked strings then the attacker would get access to the scope of your page if they previously managed to save "domain" with whatever string they wanted. In THIS case it is highly questionable what they could do other than redirect to their server since the code in `<domain>` would not be executed due to the page change
I am not sure what a location

```
window.location.href = '';executeSomethingNasty()
```

or a change that only changes the hash

```
window.location.href = window.location.href+'#stayonthepage';executeSomethingNasty()
```

Comment: how can they execute or save that changes in my server, so that all has the same href redirect? if window.location.href is readed out of the static php variable? if they change that variable in there browser and send the hole request back to the server, the server didnt catch the change from the user/browser or do i understand something wrong? so how can be that infected for other guys who dont use the same browser where the manipulation was made?

Comment: The perp has to be allowed to store the unsafe string on your server and then later you serve that string to another person. If your PHP does not get the `<domain>` from somewhere else but you create it yourself on your server, then there is no harm possible from that side

Comment: so you mean that Header always set X-Frame-Options configuration which should be set to "SAMEORIGIN" or "DENY"? sorry for my question, but i am really unsure for that. thats the reason why i ask so often atm and thank you for your friendly reply :)

Comment: Are you commenting on the right question? There are no iFrames in this question

Answer (score 0):

It's safe when `'<domain>'` just a string. But when some value of `location.href` typed by user - it's unsafe, because this construction can run javascript like `javascript: alert(document.cookie)` by specification.